# Add a link to navigator in a text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a link to seperate view inside a text widget

I tried adding Two Text Widgets and a flat button in between but it doesnt show as expected

How I want it to look like

```html
<p>This is a <a href="#">sample</a> text</p>
```

This is what i tried

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text('This is a '),
    FlatButton(
      onPress: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>View()))
      }
      child: Text('sample')
    ),
    Text(' text')
  ]
)
```

Comment: Did you try RichText?

Comment: Just checked but is it possible to add onTap to TextSpan

Comment: Yes, possible, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TapGestureRecognizer _recognizer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _recognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = (){
    print("tapped");
  };
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: 'This is a '),
            TextSpan(text: 'sample', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), recognizer: _recognizer),
            TextSpan(text: ' text'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This Looks like what i wanted